# hadoop t-file and datablock relationship?

Tags: hadoop

My understanding is that Hadoop takes a large file and saves it in chunks of "Datablocks". Are these data blocks stored in a T-file? Is the relationship between datablock and T-file 1-1?

Answer (score 2):

[HDFS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120513124017/http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/hdfs_design.html) stores large files as a series of data blocks (typically of a fixed size like 64/128/256/512 MB). Say you have a 1GB file, and a block size of 256MB - HDFS will represent this file as 4 blocks. The Name node will track what data nodes have copies (or replicas) of these blocks.

[T-Files](https://web.archive.org/web/20120717130530/http://hadoop.apache.org:80/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/file/tfile/TFile.html) are a file format, containing Key/Value pairs. Hadoop would store a T-File using one or more data blocks in HDFS (depending on the size of the T-File, and the defined block size - either the system default or file specific).

In summary, you can store any file format in HDFS, it will just be chunked up into fixed sized blocks, distributed and replicated throughout the cluster.

Comment: What is the use of datablock? Say i have 1GB file with variable sized records inside it. Each record is a byte array. If i give block size 64MB, hadoop will blindly chunk it based on file size and it is possible that half my record ends up on one data block and other half on another data block.

Comment: Part of the early process of the MapReduce job (I believe in the `InputSplit` class) is to consolidate the problem of splitting a record in half. Usually what happens is it will go backwards in the previous block until it finds the delimiter, and streams that small amount of data back to complete the record. The blocking is very transparent to the user and very rarely do you need to worry about it.

Comment: The purpose of the data block is to split the work up. A 1GB file will be split into 16 blocks, so that 16 map tasks can work on it in parallel. Since these blocks are scattered on the cluster, you can effectively load the entire file at once and process on it in parallel. In the end, this is no different than manually splitting the file up into 64MB chunks... it's just there for convenience.

Comment: @Jimm - it depends on whether the file format you have is 'splitable'. GZip for example is not splittable, you cannot seek to a random part of the file and recover the stream from that point onwards. A block compression method such as bzip however is splitable. Like orangeoctopus said, hadoop will seek to the offset, and then seek forward to find the next processable boundary (think newline for a text file, or a special 16 byte sequence for a sequence file)